# grails 3.1.3 Multiple data source with weak reference setters not working

Tags: grails

I haven't faced this situation previously in older i.e. grails 2 so unsure if this is the correct behaviour or if there is a bug.

I have followed the documentation and in my application.groovy I have dataSources with the default as is and an extra called countrycity

In my city class I have

```
package com.example.info

class City {
  String code

  static mapping={
   datasource 'countrycity'
  }
}
```

and in the other domain class

```
package com.example.users
class Address {

  Long city

  City getCity() {
     return City.get(city)
  }
  //void  setCity(City c) {city=c.id}
}
```

With no setter enabled the app starts fine, the moment I enable the void setCity line I get a stack trace like this:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table address refers to an unmapped class: com.havingfun.info.City
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55) [grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:347) [grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:336) [grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at datesite.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean '$primaryTransactionManager' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table address refers to an unmapped class: com.havingfun.info.City
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '$primaryTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table address refers to an unmapped class: com.havingfun.info.City
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table address refers to an unmapped class: com.havingfun.info.City
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table address refers to an unmapped class: com.havingfun.info.City
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1807) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1741) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.secondPassCompile(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:287) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:196) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.doBuildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:476) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:470) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:93) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `String code` to a Groovy class (in this case a Grails domain class), it looks like a public (or perhaps package-default) field, but it's a property. The Groovy compiler will convert that into an actual private field with the same name, plus the associated getter and setter methods (`String getCode()` and `void setCode(String)`). If you've defined either the getter or setter or both Groovy won't overwrite yours, it just adds the missing ones.

This works well for GORM because Hibernate doesn't know about Groovy properties - all it's looking for is matched getter/setter pairs that are interpreted to be a property. It doesn't know whether your class is from Java source or Groovy source or whether the methods were generated by Groovy or manually typed by you.

You've already got a "city" property of type Long, and adding `City getCity()` gets you half way to a second. When you add the setter you have two of the same name but with different types, which would fail on its own if Hibernate didn't complain about you seeming to want to persist a type it doesn't know how to work with.

So you'll need to rename one of them - I'd go with `Long cityId` since it's more self-descriptive and will create a `city_id` column in the database just like it would if you were mapping a foreign key to a 'city' table.

Comment: Great tip on cityId I already started doing something similar last night i.e. as it was but then transient userCity that was proper values. Then I ended up with just the Getter and was going to leave the logic of setting to helper bean that would be validating anyway. I raised question to confirm behaviour is correct. Having multiData source since to come at a cost ? I mean now I can only grab lets say transient city property via findAll{it.city.code=='AB'} i.e. forward walking through returned results rather than a straight up hibernate query (unless more complications of comma joins used)

Comment: You are correct that your queries won't be as efficient as if they were in the same database, and you won't be able to take advantage of foreign key constraints and indexes, or transactions between the two without configuring 2PC. But as long as the flexibility you gain is worth that cost you should be fine. I doubt it will be very noticeable if you're careful.